# How do I change/customize the icon for the pegman on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps-api-3

I have searched around stackexchange, but I only found questions/answers for changing the location of the pegman. Is there a way to change the source image for it? 
I have tried affecting the style like this:

```
#map-canvas > div > div:nth-child(8) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > img:nth-child(1) {
    background:url(images/man.jpg);
  }
```

but it's not showing any changes. I can't seem to find it here either: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#StreetViewService

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Pegman icon is part of the Google Streetview branding and cannot be changed.