# How to increase the size of Pegman (Google Maps Street View icon)?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How change the size of "Street View" icon (Pegman) on Google Maps API?
I don't want change the icon, only increase the size.
The current icon used by Google is http://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/pegman_v3/default/runway-1x.png. There is a larger http://maps.gstatic.com/tactile/pegman_v3/default/runway-3x.png but do not know how to set

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31151530/how-do-i-change-customize-the-icon-for-the-pegman-on-google-maps

Comment: I don't want change the icon, only increase the size

Comment: try xplore the map  div container and  the try to find it .. good luck

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the style of css class gm-svpc. Simply add this to your css:

```
.gm-svpc {
  transform: scale(1.6);
}
```